# Google translate changes Preterite into Imperfect?

Tags: gramática

I've noticed something strange, but it could be me as well?

Por ejemplo
Quisiste abrir la puerta.
You wanted to open the door.

Google translate will switch "Quisiste abrir la puerta." to "Querías abrir la puerta."
Is either ok, and its just the context that determines which is more appropriate, and if so, why does Google translate just assume it knows the context?

Comment: It does seem more likely that the wanting went on for long enough to warrant the imperfect.

Comment: That's why you can't trust google translate and actually have to learn the language. Bu the way, this site only goes **into Spanish** and not from Spanish to English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verb querer is a little unusual in the preterite/imperfect distinction, at least from an english speaker's point of view.

```
quisiste abrir la puerta
```

implies that you attempted to open the door,  while

```
querías abrir la puerta
```

does not.